# Which Event trigeer while merge/unmerging cell/Row/column in excel officejs

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

Is there any event which is trigger when row/column/cell will merge/unmerge in Excel

I try onChange event but I didn't get any thing about merge/unmerge its return only "RangeEdited" as eventType.

I want any event which trigger when user merge/unmerge cell/Row/Column in Excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript API for Office (OfficeJS) doesn't provide any specific events for that.

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on Tech Community where they are considered when the Office dev team go through the planning process, see https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .